# Scale :before when hovering

Tags: css, animation, hover, scale

**I'm trying to scale the `:before` content of my `<span>` when hovering over it.** So far the style gets applied when hovering but there are no visual changes, the `:before` remains the same scale.

*What I've got so far:*

```
<div class="comment-actions">
  <span class="comment-likes icon-ico-heart">
    12
  </span>
</div>
```

*SASS (CSS):*

```
.comment-likes
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out
  color: #92a3b9
  cursor: pointer

  &:hover::before
    transform: scale(1.5)
```

*Icomoon:*

```
.icon-ico-heart:before {
  content: "\e914";
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't transform it with the scale property but use the font-size. So:

```
.icon-ico-heart:hover:before {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works! For future viewers: you've to put the transition on the `:before`.

Comment: The question was how to scale ::before, not how to change font-size.

Answer (score 2):

Increase the `font-size` on hover and add `transition` property to it.

```
.icon-ico-heart:before {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.icon-ico-heart:hover:before {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

You can use just `transition: font 0.3s ease;` to apply transition only for font instead of `all`

Answer (score 0):

You may not able to use the scale property for fonts or icon fonts,

Instead of this you can use font size property.

Answer (score 0):

You can't transform the `::before` element because it's display type is: `display: inline`,
you have to change it to `display: inline-block` or another.

```css
.icon-ico-heart:before {
  content: "\e914";
  display:inline-block;
}
```